# Triple-DES DUKPT CBC PIN variant vs Data variant

Tags: encryption, cryptography

Does any know the difference between triple des dukpt decryption algorithm with PIN variant and Data variant?

I have done Triple DES DUKPT PIN variant, which generate session key from KSN and BDK. And then decrypt message using the session key.

How about Data variant? How is it different from PIn variant? Thank you

Comment: Welcome. We treat on this website only security related issues. Your question is purely about cryptography, so please ask it on [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) website instead.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out.... I am absolutely not sure where to post....

Comment: Post your question on this website: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/